# How would I search an element in a vector string?

Tags: c++, search

I'm trying to search a vector string for certain words.

For example,

```
vector<string> sentences = ["This is a test string","Welcome to C++!"];
string searchString = "This";
```

I tried

```cpp
if (std::find(sentences.begin(), sentences.end(), searchString) != sentences.end()) {
    cout << "Found!";
}
else {
    cout << "Not Found!";
}
```

Now this does work but only if the searchString matches the element word for word.

For example if we set

```
string searchString = "This is a test string";
```

This will return found.

How do I search the elements individually?

Thanks!

Comment: By searching elements individually, you mean if, for example, you searched for `"welcome"`, it would return the `"Welcome to C++!"` string element?

Comment: So you want to find all strings in the vector containing just a single word? Then you you need some way to iterate over the vector, giving you the strings inside it one by one. And then search the strings for the word.

Comment: `<vector>string sentences = ["This is a test string","Welcome to C++!"];` - what is that supposed to be? `vector<string> sentences = { ... };`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(std::string& s  : sentences)
{
  if(s.find(searchString) != std::string::npos)
  {
     //substring found
  }
  else
  {
     //substring not found
  }
}
```

this should work for looking for a word in each string in the vector

Answer (score 2):

There is [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) that lets you pass a predicate to be used instead of directly comparing elements for equality with a searchString:

```
auto matcher = [searchString](const std::string& element) {
    return element.find(searchString) != std::string::npos;
};

if (std::find_if(sentences.begin(), sentences.end(), matcher) != sentences.end()){
    cout << "Found!";
} else {
    cout<< "Not Found!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all the strings in your vector and check each string one by one if it contains the string you want to find. If the string contains the search term, you can return the whole element:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string findSubstr(const std::vector<std::string>& list, const std::string& search) {
    for (const std::string& str : list) {
        if (str.find(search) != std::string::npos) {
            return str;
        }
    }
    return "Not found";
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::clog << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <search term>\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<std::string> test{"This is a test string", "Welcome to C++!"};
    std::cout << findSubstr(test, argv[1]) << std::endl;
}
```